# Is this a good way to layout my view controllers

Tags: ios, swift

People usually get real frame size in `viewDidAppear()` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` to calculate their views, however I usually got problems with these approaches.

I want my views to be already calculated before they appear on the screen so `viewDidAppear()` is not suitable, `viewWillAppear()` sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't. `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` is called many times so it's not a good choice either.

So below is my way to handle it, I always get the desired results with this approach. Are there any disadvantages with this?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    // put everything needs to be calculated here
}
```

Comment: Why don’t you use auto layout?

Comment: Your view won't change size when the device is rotated.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to lay out your views that way.

The modern Apple recommendation is to avoid making manual changes to frame.

Answer (score 0):

`layoutIfNeeded`

From document : `Lays out the subviews immediately, if layout updates are pending.`

This is a synchronous call that tells the system you want a layout and redraw of a view and its subviews, and you want it done immediately without waiting for the update cycle.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622507-layoutifneeded

You should also check this WWDC video this year 
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/220/

Answer (score 0):

Put your code to viewLayoutSubViews dwlwgate method.